# Re-direct ".html" to "/"

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

In my Blog (http://ordealoftheunion.com/)
My blog was previously hosted on Blogger and then was changed to a self hosted wordpress.org blog, Lots of things (like Permalinks) remained static until they were re-indexed by Google. What i noticed is that someone links with".html" re-directed to the 404 Page instead of the new permalink structure in wordpress. for example when i clicked on an article from an old link ending in ".html" it re-directed me to the 404 page instead of the actual article (/2012/05/barack-kingfish-obama-for-president.html) Which no longer works, since the permalinks changed the article is now located at (/2012/05/barack-kingfish-obama-for-president/) to summarize how can i get .html to re-direct to "/" ?

Many Thanks

- Ruslan.K

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule **as your first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the wordpress plugin route you could use [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). After installing the plugin go to:

- Tools -> Redirection
- In the "Source URL" box add "/*.html"
- In the "Target URL" box add ""
- Tick the "Regular expression"
- Next click on the "Add redirection" button and the .html pages should redirect to /.